# Brezis' theorem 7.7: the case $k=2$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. We define by induction the subspaces
$$
D(A^{k+1}) := \{ v \in D(A^k) :Av \in D(A^k)\}
\quad \forall k \in \mathbb N^*.
$$
Then $D(A^k)$ is a Hilbert space for the inner product
$$
\langle u, v \rangle_{D(A^k)} := \sum_{j=0}^k \langle A^j u, A^j v \rangle.
$$

Let $|\cdot|_{D(A^k)}$ be the induced norm of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A^k)}$. I'm trying to prove the case $k=2$ in *Theorem 7.7* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $A$ be a self-adjoint maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. Then, given any $u_0 \in H$ there exists a unique function
> $$
> u \in C([0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C^1((0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C((0, +\infty); D(A))
> $$
> such that
> $$
> (*) \quad\begin{cases}
> \frac{d u}{d t}+A u&=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (0,+\infty), \\
> u(0)&=u_0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Moreover, we have
>
> - $|u(t)| \leq\left|u_0\right|$ and $\left|\frac{d u}{d t}(t)\right|=|Au(t)| \leq \frac{1}{t} \left|u_0\right|$ for all $t > 0$.
> - $u \in C^{k-\ell} ((0,+\infty) ; D(A^\ell))$ for all $k \in \mathbb N^*$ and $\ell=0, \ldots, k$.

I have proved for the case $k=1$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741019/brezis-theorem-7-7-uniqueness-and-existence). Now I want to tackle the case $k=2$. There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

It remains to prove $u \in C^2 ((0, +\infty); H)$. Consider the Hilbert space $H_1 = D(A)$ equipped with the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A)}$. Then the operator $A_1 :D(A_1) \subset H_1 \to H_1$ defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
D(A_1) &= D(A^2), \\
A_1 u &= Au,
\end{cases}
$$
[is maximal monotone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738989/brezis-theorem-7-5-how-is-a-1-maximal-monotone-in-h-1/4739049#4739049) and self-adjoint in $H_1$. We apply the case $k=1$ to the operator $A_1$ in the space $H_1$, we see that there is a unique function
$$
u \in C ([0, +\infty); H_1) \cap C^1 ((0, +\infty); H_1) \cap C((0, +\infty); D(A^2))
$$
that satisfies $(*)$. Since $A \in \mathcal L(H_1, H)$ and $u \in C^1 ((0, +\infty); H_1)$, we get $Au \in C^1 ((0, +\infty); H)$ and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (Au) = A \left (\frac{du}{dt} \right )
\quad \text{on} \quad (0, +\infty).
$$

Then $\frac{d u}{d t} \in C^1 ((0, +\infty); H)$ and thus  $u \in C^2 ((0, +\infty); H)$. Moreover,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left (\frac{d u}{d t} \right )+A \left (\frac{du}{dt} \right )=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (0,+\infty).
$$

---

**Update** @Kroki has found a critical mistake in my above attempt. Below is my fix.

---

Let $t_0 >0$. From the case $k=1$, we get $u(t_0) \in H_1$. We apply the case $k=1$ to the operator $A_1$ in the space $H_1$, we see that there is a unique function
$$
v \in C ([t_0, +\infty); H_1) \cap C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H_1) \cap C((t_0, +\infty); D(A^2))
$$
that satisfies
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d v}{d t}+A v&=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (t_0,+\infty), \\
v(t_0)&=u(t_0).
\end{cases}
$$

Since $A \in \mathcal L(H_1, H)$ and $v \in C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H_1)$, we get $Av \in C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H)$ and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (Av) = A \left (\frac{dv}{dt} \right )
\quad \text{on} \quad (t_0, +\infty).
$$

Then $\frac{d v}{d t} \in C^1 ((t_0, +\infty); H)$ and thus  $v \in C^2 ((t_0, +\infty); H)$. Moreover,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left (\frac{d v}{d t} \right )+A \left (\frac{dv}{dt} \right )=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (t_0,+\infty).
$$

By uniqueness, $u$ and $v$ coincide on $(t_0, +\infty)$. Because $t_0>0$ is arbitrary, we get $u \in C^2 ((0, +\infty); H)$ and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left (\frac{d u}{d t} \right )+A \left (\frac{du}{dt} \right )=0 \quad \text{on} \quad (0,+\infty).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only small mistake that you have is when you construct your solution using $A_1$, you are assuming that $u_0\in H_1$ which is not correct. Can you fix it by taking another initial value for example $u(t_0)$ for $t_0>0$?

Comment: Ah It's actually a critical mistake. The fact that $u_0$ is not necessarily in $H_1$ makes *Theorem 7.7* distinctive from *Theorem 7.4*. I have updated my thread with a fix. Could you have a check on it?

Comment: Yes your proof is now correct.

Comment: If you don't mind, please have a check on my [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741158/brezis-theorem-7-7-the-case-k-ge-3) for the remaining case $k \ge 3$.